# How to create a tab in the text inside of the <tr> </tr>

Tags: html

```html
<tr>
    <td>Where to go if sick? 
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;3 minuts ago</td>
</tr>
```

I am trying building the website but I am not sure how I can make a space between
"sick" and "3minutes ago".
I found out `&nbsp;` is a tab in HTML but I am pretty sure there is a simpler way to do this.
Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Comment: sounds like you're looking for `<br>` tag. Remove all `&nbsp;`  and add only one `<br>` tag

Comment: A `<br />` creates a new line, not a tab or spacing.

Comment: @CarlMarkham The [<br>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/text-level-semantics.html#the-br-element)  tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: `&nbsp;` is a "non-breaking space", not a tab.

Answer (score 2):

Set a width on your `td` element, then give it `display: flex` and `justify-content: space-between`.

```css
td {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>Where to go if sick?</span>
      <span>"3 minutes ago"</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Flexbox is a great tool to let the browser decide how things should be laid out, instead of giving explicit values to everything.  See the MDN docs on [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox).

The reason I added `span` to each text snippet is so that there are 2 discrete child elements of the `td` so flexbox knows which elements to put `space-between`.

###### Another Solution:

If you are unable to set a fixed width on your `td` element, you can achieve the same effect using flexbox's `gap` property.

```css
td {
  display: flex;
  gap: 4rem;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>Where to go if sick?</span>
      <span>"3 minutes ago"</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be a table? If so, you can use padding:

```
<table style="border-collapse: collapse">
  <tr>
   <td style="padding-right: 25px">
       Where to go if sick?
   </td>
   <td>
      "3 minuts ago"
   </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Also you can add child elements into td and set margin:

```
<tr>
  <td>
   <span style="margin-right: 25px">Where to go if sick?</span>
   <span>"3 minuts ago"</span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

If you don't need a table. Just add margin-right:

```
<p><span style="margin-right: 25px">Where to go if sick?</span> "3 minuts ago"</p>
```

Comment: Thank you! so much!

Comment: This is a quick and dirty way to achieve the result. The other answer by @PsiKai is a better approach.

Comment: I disagree. It is not known whether a fixed width is suitable for the author.

Comment: @olieinykov I agree with your assessment.  I added another flexbox solution that doesn't rely on a fixed width to my answer.